# trying to use switch statement in C#

Tags: c#

I am checking  a value in textbox control “txtType” and I have 3 possible values: it is either TypeA, TypeB or TypeC.  So all what I want to do is:
This is what I have so far

```
string myType= ((TextBox)DV_LogAdd.FindControl("txtType")).Text.ToString();
int  updatedType;
If string myType = ‘TypeA’ then set updatedType to 1
If string myType = ‘TypeB’ then set updatedType to 2
If string myType = ‘TypeC’ then set updatedType to 3
```

I have tried to use switch statement but messed up.

Comment: Post what you have so far.

Comment: This code doesn't look like any known Language and surely it is not C#, what Language is that?

Comment: It's probably pseudocode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this :

```
        string myType= ((TextBox)DV_LogAdd.FindControl("txtType")).Text.ToString();
        int updateType = 0;
        switch (myType)
        {
            case "TypeA":
                updateType = 1;
                break;
            case "TypeB":
                updateType = 2;
                break;
            case "TypeC":
                updateType = 3;
                break;
            default :
                throw new ArgumentException("txtType value not supported :"+myType);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string myType= ((TextBox)DV_LogAdd.FindControl("txtType")).Text.ToString();
int updatedType;
switch(myType) 
{ 
   case "TypeA"
      updatedType = 1;
      break;
   case "TypeB":
      updatedType = 2;
      break;
   case "TypeC"
      updatedType = 3;
      break;
   default:
      updatedType= 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't know whats with downvote with the answer. Have cancelled it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
switch(myType)
{
    case "TypeA":
        updatedType = 1;
    break;
    case "TypeB":
        updatedType = 2;
    break;
    case "TypeC":
        updatedType = 3;
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `switch` statement is fully explained here http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/06tc147t(v=vs.80).aspx and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/k0t5wee3(v=vs.80).aspx

Using switch your code will look like:

```
string myType= ((TextBox)DV_LogAdd.FindControl("txtType")).Text.ToString();
int updateType = 0;
switch (myType)
{
    case "TypeA": 
        updateType = 1;
        break;
    case "TypeB":
        updateType = 2;
        break;
    case "TypeC":
        updateType = 3;
        break;
    default:
        // Do some stuff
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

```
        string myType= ((TextBox)DV_LogAdd.FindControl("txtType")).Text.ToString();
        int updatedType;
        switch (myType)
        {
            case "TypeA": updatedType = 1;
                break;
            case "TypeB": updatedType = 2;
                break;
            case "TypeC": updatedType = 3;
                break;
            default: updatedType = 0; //Optionnal if myType not in (TypeA, TypeB, TypeC); otherwise, you muste initialize updatedType
                break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You switch statement looks nothing like C# but just psuedo code, but the C# equivalent is:

```
switch(myType){
 case "TypeA":
  updateType=1;
  break;
 case "TypeB":
  updateType=2;
  break;
 case "TypeC":
  updateType=3;
  break;
 default:
  break;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 1):

this works for me:

```
string myType  = "typeB";

int updatedType  = 0;
switch(myType) {
    case "typeA":
        updatedType = 1;
        break;
    case "typeB":
        updatedType = 2;
        break;
    case "typeC":
        updatedType = 3;
        break;
}

Console.WriteLine("number: " + updatedType .ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If i got you correctly i think what you want is....

```
string str = "";
int  updatedType;

foreach(Control c in this.controls)
{
   if(c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox) && c.Name == "txtType")
   {
      str = c.Text;
   }
}

switch(str)
{
   case "TypeA":
        updatedType = 1;
        break;
   case "TypeB":
        updatedType = 2;
        break;
   case "TypeC":
        updatedType = 3;
        break;
   default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] data = {"", "TypeA", "TypeB", "TypeC"};

string myType = ((TextBox)DV_LogAdd.FindControl("txtType")).Text;
int updatedType = Array.IndexOf(data, myType);
```

Note: It will return -1, if it can't find the item in the array